# How to get an Instance of ServiceManager into a Model in ZF2

Tags: php, orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

Okay so I'm using ZF2 with Doctrine's ORM Module

I have a model called `ProjectGateway.php`

My question is how do I access the service locator via `getServiceLocator()->` I get call to undefined class error.

Does the model need to extend a class?  Am I missing some imports?

I am able to access it via the controller.

Any steer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Add the model as a service in the `ServiceManager` configuration, and make sure the model class implements the `Zend\Service\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` class.
2. Manually add the service manager into the model by a getter/setter through another class that uses the `ServiceManager`, eg. a `Controller`.

Method 1:

```
// module.config.php
<?php
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'ProjectGateway' => 'Application\Model\ProjectGateway',
        )
    )
);
```

Now make sure your model implements the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` and its methods:

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ProjectGateway implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface 
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

From a controller you are now able to get your `ProjectGateway` by doing:

```
$projectGateway = $this->getServiceLocator->get('ProjectGateway');
```

Consequently you have now the ServiceManager available in your `ProjectGateway` class by doing the following:

```
public function someMethodInProjectGateway()
{
    $serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
}
```

**UPDATE 04/06/2014:** Method 2:

Basically what you need in your model is a getter/setter for the `ServiceManager` as shown in method 1, which is shown below:

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ProjectGateway implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface 
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do from somewhere else (e.g. a `Controller`) is parse the `ServiceManager` in there:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Application\Model\ProjectGateway;

class SomeController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $model = new ProjectGateway();

        // Now set the ServiceLocator in our model
        $model->setServiceLocator($this->getServiceLocator());
     }
}
```

It is nothing more than that.

Using method 2 however means that the `ProjectGateway` model is not readily available throughout your application on-demand. You'll need to instantiate and set the `ServiceManager` every time.

However, as a last note, it must be noted that method 1 is not that much heavier in resources than method 2, as the model is not instantiated before you call it for the first time.

Comment: Okay thank for that. Ive edited the changes you suggested but I'm now returning an error Fatal error: Declaration of Base\Model\ProjectGateway::setServiceLocator() must be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::setServiceLocator(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) in /Volumes/Data/Sites/cole/module/Base/src/Base/Model/ProjectGateway.php on line 8

Comment: You can take a look at the Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and copy over the definition from there. It should be exactly like that one. I should've tested the code, but I just did it out of the top of my head.

Comment: I just took a look at it seems I forgot a use class. Can you add this to the other use please: `use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;`